# Document Timer on Sharepoint Documents Indivdual Files

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have Sharepoint Designer 2013 and a Office4 Sharepoint Site,
I have a Sharepoint Documents with some files inside. I would like one of these files in the folder for example an excel file to be opened regularly. Is it possible to set a timer when a file has been opened and if the file has not been opened for example for 365 days or 24 hours, an email is sent to a specific person letting them know the file has not been opened/modified.

I want to use Workflow to ensure files are regularly kept up to date, I only want one of the files in one of the folders have this timer set. This is because not all files need to be regularly updated. There may be a time when two files in a folder need a timer

Appreciate any help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Workflow does not have a trigger for opening files. What we have is created, created or modified triggers. Even event receiver will not be able to monitoring open events. Or you can ask the end users to modify the documents to update with something like last viewed date.

And if you want to make the workflow only works for a certain file, you may need to add an if condition inside the workflow to skip the events which not-required files kick the workflow to run.